# Docker OPTIONS= vs DOCKER_OPTS 1.12.6 vs 1.13.1

Tags: docker

I just upgraded a Atomic host (RHEL Atomic Host release 7.4) and the version of Docker went from 1.12.6 to 1.13.1. So far so good.

However, in my /etc/sysconfig/docker-latest config file I HAD a line:

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false --bip=10.20.104.1/24 --mtu=1472'
```

However, for some reasons, Docker refuse to start with that.

When I change OPTIONS= for DOCKER_OPTS= , it seem to work.

I cant find any documentation on that change, neither if there a behaviour change to expect.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that the best way to do now is this,

Point OPTIONS= to a daemon.json like this:

```
OPTIONS='--config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json'
```

Here is the page with all the options. It seem to replace the CONFIG= now....

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/